# How hide column without save place in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In manual to bootstrap is class offset. It hide column with save place in grid.

How hide column without save place?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but check out the responsive utilities: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities.  These will allow you to hide or show elements for individual breakpoints.  If I misunderstood the question, please give an example and I'll try to answer.

Comment: i solved.  class hidden-xs